# Add another class on a specific div on input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I'm trying to find a solution for my searchbar problem. The searchbar should behave differently on smartphones so I need to add another class to the div, where the searchbar is placed.

When I click on the input field, the div with the class "highlighted" should get another class. Until now I just found solution to add a class to a next or partent div, but that's not what I was searching for.

```html
<div class="highlighted">
  <div class="region region-highlighted">
    <section id="block-x" class="contextual-region block clearfix">
      <div data-contextual-id="block:block=x:langcode=en|block_content:block_content=20:changed=1462269631&amp;ds_bundle=basic&amp;ds_view_mode=default&amp;langcode=en"></div>
      <div class="field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field--item">
        <p>x</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="search-block-form contextual-region block block-search" data-drupal-selector="search-block-form" id="block-bootstrap-search" role="search">

      <div data-contextual-id="block:block=bootstrap_search:langcode=en"></div>
      <form action="/search/node" method="get" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <div class="form-item js-form-item form-type-search js-form-type-search form-item-keys js-form-item-keys form-no-label form-group">
          <label for="edit-keys--2" class="control-label sr-only">Search</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." data-drupal-selector="edit-keys" class="form-search form-control" placeholder="Search" type="search" id="edit-keys--2" name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" value="Search" class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-primary btn icon-only" name=""><span class="sr-only">Search</span><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div id="edit-keys--2--description" class="description help-block">Enter the terms you wish to search for.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions form-group js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" id="edit-actions"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's the jquery/css?

Comment: .highlighted:focus psuedoclass should do what you want. Keep in mind older browsers may not support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying, but something like `$('.highlighted').addClass('otherclass');` should work.

**Edit after comment:**

```
$('.input-group input').focus(function () { $('.highlighted').addClass('open'); })
$('.input-group input').blur(function () {$('.highlighted').removeClass('open'); });
```

(The only change needed to your code was the last selector. I'm just putting it in 2 lines for clarity.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats almost what im searching for, but this should only happen, when I clicked inside the input of the search bar. So I tried this, but the class wasnt removed when the input field wasnt on focus.

$('.input-group input').focus(function () {
 $('.highlighted').addClass('open');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});